# Handoff with different iPhones

Tags: iphone

Which iPhone will work with handoff in between macs and itself. I'm looking into buying one and I want to make sure I could use handoff.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Handoff' functionality depends on your iOS version and device hardware, as well as your Mac hardware. As it states in in the [Apple support page for 'Handoff'](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18754?locale=en_US):

> Handoff works with several apps that come with OS X Yosemite and iOS 8: Calendar, Contacts, Mail, Maps, Messages, Notes, Phone (iOS only), Reminders, and Safari. It also works with Keynote v6.5, Numbers v3.5, and Pages v5.5 for Mac, and Keynote, Numbers, and Pages v2.5 for iOS. Third-party apps may also work with Handoff.

iOS hardware that is compatible with Handoff:

- iPhone 4S (sharing iPhone calls only)
- iPhone 5 or later
- iPod Touch (5th generation)
- iPad 4th gen and iPad Air/Air 2
- iPad mini, mini with Retina display and mini 3

Further requirements for specific features are found on [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204689).

Mac hardware that is compatible with Handoff:

- MacBook Air (Mid 2012 and later)
- MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 and later)
- iMac (Late 2012 and later)
- Mac mini (Late 2012 and later)
- Mac Pro (Late 2013)

Comment: Just because a device can run iOS 8 doesn't mean that all features of it are available. Handoff requires specific hardware in the phone, too. I edited your post with a corrected list of compatible devices. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204689

Comment: That is good to know.